# How to load 2 different apis response into single recylverview with one by one?

Tags: android

I want to load the response from two different APIs in the same recycler-view but first two items from the first API and then the first item from second same again third, the fourth item from the first API and second item from second API same like this.

2 items from the first API, 1 item from the second API like that I want to load into the `recylerview`. I don't know any idea. Please help me.
I know simply to load both APIs response into `recylerview` that is simple,

If we declare the ArrayList globally means we can add both responses, but this scenario is different. Kindly give some idea.

Comment: Both apis will return same data types? I just want to know if you are using one layout for recycler view items or two different layout(depending on the apis data types).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way to approach your problem is to make a model for your RecyclerView.
so in this way, you can make a single list item and then feed it to the adapter.
and there on using a type (or something similar) decide which type to show in recycler view.

since you didn't provide any code I'm going to provide a sample from the top of my head!:

recyclerview model:

```
public class RecyclerViewModel{

    public static final int RESPONSE_ONE_ITEM_TYPE = 1;
    public static final int RESPONSE_TWO_ITEM_TYPE = 2;

    private final ResponseModel1 item1;
    private final ResponseModel2 item2;
    private final int type;

    //remember to pass only one item and keep the other one null
    public RecyclerViewModel(ResponseModel1 item1, ResponseModel2 item2, int type) {
        this.item1 = item1;
        this.item2 = item2;
        this.type = type;
    }


    public ResponseModel1 getItem1() {
        return item1;
    }

    public ResponseModel2 getItem2() {
        return item2;
    }

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

the recyclerview apdater should look like something similiar:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

    private final List<RecyclerViewModel> items;

    public Adapter(List<RecyclerViewModel> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == RecyclerViewModel.RESPONSE_ONE_ITEM_TYPE)
        return new ApiResponse1ViewHolder();
        else {
            return new ApiResponse2ViewHolder();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (getItemViewType(position) == RecyclerViewModel.RESPONSE_ONE_ITEM_TYPE){
            //bind the api response one item view holder
            items.get(position).item1
        }else{
            //bind the api response two item view holder
            items.get(position).item2
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return items.get(position).type;
    }
}
```

hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Make a DataAll class having two ArrayList.

```
DataAll{ 
     ArrayList<dataType> data1;
     ArrayList<dataType> data2;

     Public dataType getDataAtPos1(int pos){
               return data1.get(pos);
     }

     public dataType getDataAtPos2(int pos){
               return data2.get(pos);
     }

     public int getSize(){
               return data2.size()+data1.size();
      }
}
```

I leave further things on you. Now inside your RecyclerView adapter have a DataAll object which stores the data and in method onBindViewHolder do following:

```
onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position){ 
       dataType currentData;
        if(position+1 %3 == 0){
                 currentData = dataAll.getDataAtPos2((position+1)/3 - 1);
        }
        else{
                  currentData = dataAll.getDataAtPos1(position - (position/3));
        }
    }
```

Now populate your ui using currentData. Comment for any further query.